# how to replace span content with some dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string, its value is

```
"My name is <span data-name-attribute></span>  <span class="icon icon>is</span>  <span data-job-attribute></span>. May I help you "
```

and I need to split these based on starting and closing span tags and need the final output should be

```
Your name is John and my profession is Welder. May I help you.
```

Whereas "John" is dyncamic value came from replacing  after some iteration and "my profession is" is replaced by is and  is replaced with "Welder"

Any help will be highly helpful and thanks in advance

Comment: May be you can use html() to print the string as html and add values to attributes targeting span elements and get back the result? just create a dummy element to add html and once retrieved remove it from dom

Comment: Are you able to change the content of the string to something more usable?

Comment: my concern is i need to replace   <span data-name-attribute></span> with John like wise rest things

Answer (score 0):

Having your html like this:

`<p class="example">His name is <span data-name>unknown</span>.</p>`

You can target your span and change it's text like this:

`$('[data-name]').text("John" );`

Example on codingground: http://tpcg.io/WHcXCw

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic way of achieving that result.

```js
// store the information in an object for convenience
const obj = {name: 'John', job: 'Welder'};
const str = 'My name is <span data-name-attribute></span>  <span class="icon icon">is</span>  <span data-job-attribute></span>. May i help you?';

// add the string to the document body as HTML
document.body.innerHTML = str;

// grab the relevant span elements
const name = document.body.querySelector('[data-name-attribute]')
const job = document.body.querySelector('[data-job-attribute]');

// insert the name
name.textContent = obj.name;

// add the profession text after the name span
name.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', ' and my profession');

// add the job text
job.textContent = obj.job;
```

The better way of doing it would be to hold the string as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in which variable values can be inserted.

```js
const obj = {name: 'John', job: 'Welder'};

function replacer({name, job}) {
  return `My name is ${name} and my profession is ${job}. May i help you?`;
}

document.body.innerHTML = replacer(obj);
```